# Highlighting the Current Day in Outlook 2013 Calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2013

In Microsoft Outlook 2013, the current day is highlighted by a slightly different color blue at the top of the day.  Is there a way to alter this highlighting to make it more obvious at a glance to see the current date?

Comment: I manually created 0min long appointment with subject "NOW" and a nice orange class. I then run this PowerShell script to keep it starting at current time: https://0bin.net/paste/kUp5SqJqj+P-Idmb#286HTTh3Q9GkUD6ic92L55PTIJ6LB9YnikHiDsRlHvw

Answer (score 10):

You can do this:

1. choose default color grey
2. right click the calendar
3. in the context menu choose "View Settings..."
4. choose "Conditional Formatting..."
5. now add a bright color with the advanced condition to match when
   start and end date equals today
6. enjoy and never attend meetings again today which are really scheduled for tomorrow :)

Note that recurring appointments might be colored even if they are not today.

See the pictures:
[image: Calendar]
[image: condition]

Comment: > Note that recurring appointments might be colored even if they are not today. Not "might". They do. Each one. So unfortunately, another basic feature where Outlook fails miserably :-(

Comment: @user351143 You can get around this by adding another condition - for Field, choose "Recurring" (from the "Frequently used fields" selection), and for "Condition", choose "no".

Comment: @pgl This will most likely ignore recurring events that occurs today -- as per comments for similar answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1255813/156554).

Comment: @trejder Thanks for pointing that out. I don't use Outlook Calendar anymore, so I have no way to test this to see if you're right or not!

Answer (score 0):

There's a Developer solution to get something close, by creating a dummy appointment named `NOW`, assign a dedicated color to it, and the VBA code given below is automatically called every minute to refresh its date and time. The name `NOW` is important because it's used to identify this special appointment by the macro, but you may rename it at both places if you wish.

See the final result, I have chosen to assign this `NOW` dummy appointment the green color: 
[image: Outlook Calendar NOW dummy appointment]

Big picture: 
[image: Outlook Calendar]

Here is the VBA macro to refresh the date and time of the appointment named `NOW` (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to display the Visual Basic editor):

```
Sub ActualizeAppointmentNow()
    Dim oApptItem As AppointmentItem
    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oItems As Items
    Set oFolder = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set oItems = oFolder.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = 'NOW'")
    If oItems.count = 0 Then
        Set oApptItem = oFolder.Items.Add(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
        oApptItem.Subject = "NOW"
    End If
    If oItems.count = 1 Then
        Set oApptItem = oItems(1)
        On Error Resume Next
        oApptItem.Start = Now
        oApptItem.End = Now
        oApptItem.Start = Now
        oApptItem.End = Now
        On Error GoTo 0
        oApptItem.ReminderSet = False
        Call oApptItem.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the explanation about the code to add, to trigger the VBA macro above automatically every minute (be careful, use the answer with version corresponding to your Outlook application, either 32 or 64 bits, latest applications use 64 bits):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257985/outlook-vba-run-a-code-every-half-an-hour

I just changed this part of their code to call my macro:

```
Public Sub TriggerTimer(ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, ByVal idevent As Long, ByVal Systime As Long)
  Call ActualizeAppointmentNow
End Sub
```

The only little drawback is that at each start of Outlook, you have this little security popup, and you should click `Enable Macros`, but personally I start Outlook only once a day so it's not much trouble: 
[image: Outlook security popup at startup]

Answer (score 0):

The top answer as of April 2021 fails to highlight the whole day, just events in that day. Thus if you have no events, nothing is highlighted.

## I think the author was looking for something more like this:

[image]

Below is the steps to get the background hours for a whole day highlighted as mentioned by [Kylie on slipstick](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/today-stand-calendar/#comment-213559) and tested on Office 365.

### For a quick semi-manual "Today" highlighting:

1. Create an appointment that last from 12am today to 12am the next
   day (this keeps the appointment from splitting the day).
2. Set up conditional formatting for that appointment:

- Right Click and choose view settings

[image: View Settings]

- Choose `Conditional formatting`

  - `New`
  - Assign: `Name` and `Color`
  - Choose the `Condition` button
  - Under `Define one Or more Criteria`

    1. Choose the `Feild` dropdown.
    2. `Date/Time fields`
    3. `Start`
    4. For the `Condition` dropdown choose `Today`
    5. Press the `Add to list` Button
    6. Choose the `Feild` dropdown.
    7. `Date/Time fields`
    8. `Duration`
    9. For the `Condition` dropdown choose `Equals`
    10. Under `Value:` type `24 hours`
    11. Press the `Add to list` Button

[image: Conditionally Format]

You can stop here if you want and just drag your one appointment from one day to the next.

### Automating daily highlighting

If you prefer to automate the daily highlighting a bit more, you'll need to generate a 24 hour event for each day.

1. You can do this rapidly by creating a CSV file with the following fields in a spreadsheet (use what ever you want as the subject):

[image: CSV File]

**For 2021** you can just copy this into a text file and save:

```
Subject,Start Time,Start Date,End Time,End Date
Day 1 Week 1,0:00:00,01/01/21,0:00:00,01/02/21
Day 2 Week 1,0:00:00,01/02/21,0:00:00,01/03/21
Day 3 Week 2,0:00:00,01/03/21,0:00:00,01/04/21
Day 4 Week 2,0:00:00,01/04/21,0:00:00,01/05/21
Day 5 Week 2,0:00:00,01/05/21,0:00:00,01/06/21
Day 6 Week 2,0:00:00,01/06/21,0:00:00,01/07/21
Day 7 Week 2,0:00:00,01/07/21,0:00:00,01/08/21
Day 8 Week 2,0:00:00,01/08/21,0:00:00,01/09/21
Day 9 Week 2,0:00:00,01/09/21,0:00:00,01/10/21
Day 10 Week 3,0:00:00,01/10/21,0:00:00,01/11/21
Day 11 Week 3,0:00:00,01/11/21,0:00:00,01/12/21
Day 12 Week 3,0:00:00,01/12/21,0:00:00,01/13/21
Day 13 Week 3,0:00:00,01/13/21,0:00:00,01/14/21
Day 14 Week 3,0:00:00,01/14/21,0:00:00,01/15/21
Day 15 Week 3,0:00:00,01/15/21,0:00:00,01/16/21
Day 16 Week 3,0:00:00,01/16/21,0:00:00,01/17/21
Day 17 Week 4,0:00:00,01/17/21,0:00:00,01/18/21
Day 18 Week 4,0:00:00,01/18/21,0:00:00,01/19/21
Day 19 Week 4,0:00:00,01/19/21,0:00:00,01/20/21
Day 20 Week 4,0:00:00,01/20/21,0:00:00,01/21/21
Day 21 Week 4,0:00:00,01/21/21,0:00:00,01/22/21
Day 22 Week 4,0:00:00,01/22/21,0:00:00,01/23/21
Day 23 Week 4,0:00:00,01/23/21,0:00:00,01/24/21
Day 24 Week 5,0:00:00,01/24/21,0:00:00,01/25/21
Day 25 Week 5,0:00:00,01/25/21,0:00:00,01/26/21
Day 26 Week 5,0:00:00,01/26/21,0:00:00,01/27/21
Day 27 Week 5,0:00:00,01/27/21,0:00:00,01/28/21
Day 28 Week 5,0:00:00,01/28/21,0:00:00,01/29/21
Day 29 Week 5,0:00:00,01/29/21,0:00:00,01/30/21
Day 30 Week 5,0:00:00,01/30/21,0:00:00,01/31/21
Day 31 Week 6,0:00:00,01/31/21,0:00:00,02/01/21
Day 32 Week 6,0:00:00,02/01/21,0:00:00,02/02/21
Day 33 Week 6,0:00:00,02/02/21,0:00:00,02/03/21
Day 34 Week 6,0:00:00,02/03/21,0:00:00,02/04/21
Day 35 Week 6,0:00:00,02/04/21,0:00:00,02/05/21
Day 36 Week 6,0:00:00,02/05/21,0:00:00,02/06/21
Day 37 Week 6,0:00:00,02/06/21,0:00:00,02/07/21
Day 38 Week 7,0:00:00,02/07/21,0:00:00,02/08/21
Day 39 Week 7,0:00:00,02/08/21,0:00:00,02/09/21
Day 40 Week 7,0:00:00,02/09/21,0:00:00,02/10/21
Day 41 Week 7,0:00:00,02/10/21,0:00:00,02/11/21
Day 42 Week 7,0:00:00,02/11/21,0:00:00,02/12/21
Day 43 Week 7,0:00:00,02/12/21,0:00:00,02/13/21
Day 44 Week 7,0:00:00,02/13/21,0:00:00,02/14/21
Day 45 Week 8,0:00:00,02/14/21,0:00:00,02/15/21
Day 46 Week 8,0:00:00,02/15/21,0:00:00,02/16/21
Day 47 Week 8,0:00:00,02/16/21,0:00:00,02/17/21
Day 48 Week 8,0:00:00,02/17/21,0:00:00,02/18/21
Day 49 Week 8,0:00:00,02/18/21,0:00:00,02/19/21
Day 50 Week 8,0:00:00,02/19/21,0:00:00,02/20/21
Day 51 Week 8,0:00:00,02/20/21,0:00:00,02/21/21
Day 52 Week 9,0:00:00,02/21/21,0:00:00,02/22/21
Day 53 Week 9,0:00:00,02/22/21,0:00:00,02/23/21
Day 54 Week 9,0:00:00,02/23/21,0:00:00,02/24/21
Day 55 Week 9,0:00:00,02/24/21,0:00:00,02/25/21
Day 56 Week 9,0:00:00,02/25/21,0:00:00,02/26/21
Day 57 Week 9,0:00:00,02/26/21,0:00:00,02/27/21
Day 58 Week 9,0:00:00,02/27/21,0:00:00,02/28/21
Day 59 Week 10,0:00:00,02/28/21,0:00:00,03/01/21
Day 60 Week 10,0:00:00,03/01/21,0:00:00,03/02/21
Day 61 Week 10,0:00:00,03/02/21,0:00:00,03/03/21
Day 62 Week 10,0:00:00,03/03/21,0:00:00,03/04/21
Day 63 Week 10,0:00:00,03/04/21,0:00:00,03/05/21
Day 64 Week 10,0:00:00,03/05/21,0:00:00,03/06/21
Day 65 Week 10,0:00:00,03/06/21,0:00:00,03/07/21
Day 66 Week 11,0:00:00,03/07/21,0:00:00,03/08/21
Day 67 Week 11,0:00:00,03/08/21,0:00:00,03/09/21
Day 68 Week 11,0:00:00,03/09/21,0:00:00,03/10/21
Day 69 Week 11,0:00:00,03/10/21,0:00:00,03/11/21
Day 70 Week 11,0:00:00,03/11/21,0:00:00,03/12/21
Day 71 Week 11,0:00:00,03/12/21,0:00:00,03/13/21
Day 72 Week 11,0:00:00,03/13/21,0:00:00,03/14/21
Day 73 Week 12,0:00:00,03/14/21,0:00:00,03/15/21
Day 74 Week 12,0:00:00,03/15/21,0:00:00,03/16/21
Day 75 Week 12,0:00:00,03/16/21,0:00:00,03/17/21
Day 76 Week 12,0:00:00,03/17/21,0:00:00,03/18/21
Day 77 Week 12,0:00:00,03/18/21,0:00:00,03/19/21
Day 78 Week 12,0:00:00,03/19/21,0:00:00,03/20/21
Day 79 Week 12,0:00:00,03/20/21,0:00:00,03/21/21
Day 80 Week 13,0:00:00,03/21/21,0:00:00,03/22/21
Day 81 Week 13,0:00:00,03/22/21,0:00:00,03/23/21
Day 82 Week 13,0:00:00,03/23/21,0:00:00,03/24/21
Day 83 Week 13,0:00:00,03/24/21,0:00:00,03/25/21
Day 84 Week 13,0:00:00,03/25/21,0:00:00,03/26/21
Day 85 Week 13,0:00:00,03/26/21,0:00:00,03/27/21
Day 86 Week 13,0:00:00,03/27/21,0:00:00,03/28/21
Day 87 Week 14,0:00:00,03/28/21,0:00:00,03/29/21
Day 88 Week 14,0:00:00,03/29/21,0:00:00,03/30/21
Day 89 Week 14,0:00:00,03/30/21,0:00:00,03/31/21
Day 90 Week 14,0:00:00,03/31/21,0:00:00,04/01/21
Day 91 Week 14,0:00:00,04/01/21,0:00:00,04/02/21
Day 92 Week 14,0:00:00,04/02/21,0:00:00,04/03/21
Day 93 Week 14,0:00:00,04/03/21,0:00:00,04/04/21
Day 94 Week 15,0:00:00,04/04/21,0:00:00,04/05/21
Day 95 Week 15,0:00:00,04/05/21,0:00:00,04/06/21
Day 96 Week 15,0:00:00,04/06/21,0:00:00,04/07/21
Day 97 Week 15,0:00:00,04/07/21,0:00:00,04/08/21
Day 98 Week 15,0:00:00,04/08/21,0:00:00,04/09/21
Day 99 Week 15,0:00:00,04/09/21,0:00:00,04/10/21
Day 100 Week 15,0:00:00,04/10/21,0:00:00,04/11/21
Day 101 Week 16,0:00:00,04/11/21,0:00:00,04/12/21
Day 102 Week 16,0:00:00,04/12/21,0:00:00,04/13/21
Day 103 Week 16,0:00:00,04/13/21,0:00:00,04/14/21
Day 104 Week 16,0:00:00,04/14/21,0:00:00,04/15/21
Day 105 Week 16,0:00:00,04/15/21,0:00:00,04/16/21
Day 106 Week 16,0:00:00,04/16/21,0:00:00,04/17/21
Day 107 Week 16,0:00:00,04/17/21,0:00:00,04/18/21
Day 108 Week 17,0:00:00,04/18/21,0:00:00,04/19/21
Day 109 Week 17,0:00:00,04/19/21,0:00:00,04/20/21
Day 110 Week 17,0:00:00,04/20/21,0:00:00,04/21/21
Day 111 Week 17,0:00:00,04/21/21,0:00:00,04/22/21
Day 112 Week 17,0:00:00,04/22/21,0:00:00,04/23/21
Day 113 Week 17,0:00:00,04/23/21,0:00:00,04/24/21
Day 114 Week 17,0:00:00,04/24/21,0:00:00,04/25/21
Day 115 Week 18,0:00:00,04/25/21,0:00:00,04/26/21
Day 116 Week 18,0:00:00,04/26/21,0:00:00,04/27/21
Day 117 Week 18,0:00:00,04/27/21,0:00:00,04/28/21
Day 118 Week 18,0:00:00,04/28/21,0:00:00,04/29/21
Day 119 Week 18,0:00:00,04/29/21,0:00:00,04/30/21
Day 120 Week 18,0:00:00,04/30/21,0:00:00,05/01/21
Day 121 Week 18,0:00:00,05/01/21,0:00:00,05/02/21
Day 122 Week 19,0:00:00,05/02/21,0:00:00,05/03/21
Day 123 Week 19,0:00:00,05/03/21,0:00:00,05/04/21
Day 124 Week 19,0:00:00,05/04/21,0:00:00,05/05/21
Day 125 Week 19,0:00:00,05/05/21,0:00:00,05/06/21
Day 126 Week 19,0:00:00,05/06/21,0:00:00,05/07/21
Day 127 Week 19,0:00:00,05/07/21,0:00:00,05/08/21
Day 128 Week 19,0:00:00,05/08/21,0:00:00,05/09/21
Day 129 Week 20,0:00:00,05/09/21,0:00:00,05/10/21
Day 130 Week 20,0:00:00,05/10/21,0:00:00,05/11/21
Day 131 Week 20,0:00:00,05/11/21,0:00:00,05/12/21
Day 132 Week 20,0:00:00,05/12/21,0:00:00,05/13/21
Day 133 Week 20,0:00:00,05/13/21,0:00:00,05/14/21
Day 134 Week 20,0:00:00,05/14/21,0:00:00,05/15/21
Day 135 Week 20,0:00:00,05/15/21,0:00:00,05/16/21
Day 136 Week 21,0:00:00,05/16/21,0:00:00,05/17/21
Day 137 Week 21,0:00:00,05/17/21,0:00:00,05/18/21
Day 138 Week 21,0:00:00,05/18/21,0:00:00,05/19/21
Day 139 Week 21,0:00:00,05/19/21,0:00:00,05/20/21
Day 140 Week 21,0:00:00,05/20/21,0:00:00,05/21/21
Day 141 Week 21,0:00:00,05/21/21,0:00:00,05/22/21
Day 142 Week 21,0:00:00,05/22/21,0:00:00,05/23/21
Day 143 Week 22,0:00:00,05/23/21,0:00:00,05/24/21
Day 144 Week 22,0:00:00,05/24/21,0:00:00,05/25/21
Day 145 Week 22,0:00:00,05/25/21,0:00:00,05/26/21
Day 146 Week 22,0:00:00,05/26/21,0:00:00,05/27/21
Day 147 Week 22,0:00:00,05/27/21,0:00:00,05/28/21
Day 148 Week 22,0:00:00,05/28/21,0:00:00,05/29/21
Day 149 Week 22,0:00:00,05/29/21,0:00:00,05/30/21
Day 150 Week 23,0:00:00,05/30/21,0:00:00,05/31/21
Day 151 Week 23,0:00:00,05/31/21,0:00:00,06/01/21
Day 152 Week 23,0:00:00,06/01/21,0:00:00,06/02/21
Day 153 Week 23,0:00:00,06/02/21,0:00:00,06/03/21
Day 154 Week 23,0:00:00,06/03/21,0:00:00,06/04/21
Day 155 Week 23,0:00:00,06/04/21,0:00:00,06/05/21
Day 156 Week 23,0:00:00,06/05/21,0:00:00,06/06/21
Day 157 Week 24,0:00:00,06/06/21,0:00:00,06/07/21
Day 158 Week 24,0:00:00,06/07/21,0:00:00,06/08/21
Day 159 Week 24,0:00:00,06/08/21,0:00:00,06/09/21
Day 160 Week 24,0:00:00,06/09/21,0:00:00,06/10/21
Day 161 Week 24,0:00:00,06/10/21,0:00:00,06/11/21
Day 162 Week 24,0:00:00,06/11/21,0:00:00,06/12/21
Day 163 Week 24,0:00:00,06/12/21,0:00:00,06/13/21
Day 164 Week 25,0:00:00,06/13/21,0:00:00,06/14/21
Day 165 Week 25,0:00:00,06/14/21,0:00:00,06/15/21
Day 166 Week 25,0:00:00,06/15/21,0:00:00,06/16/21
Day 167 Week 25,0:00:00,06/16/21,0:00:00,06/17/21
Day 168 Week 25,0:00:00,06/17/21,0:00:00,06/18/21
Day 169 Week 25,0:00:00,06/18/21,0:00:00,06/19/21
Day 170 Week 25,0:00:00,06/19/21,0:00:00,06/20/21
Day 171 Week 26,0:00:00,06/20/21,0:00:00,06/21/21
Day 172 Week 26,0:00:00,06/21/21,0:00:00,06/22/21
Day 173 Week 26,0:00:00,06/22/21,0:00:00,06/23/21
Day 174 Week 26,0:00:00,06/23/21,0:00:00,06/24/21
Day 175 Week 26,0:00:00,06/24/21,0:00:00,06/25/21
Day 176 Week 26,0:00:00,06/25/21,0:00:00,06/26/21
Day 177 Week 26,0:00:00,06/26/21,0:00:00,06/27/21
Day 178 Week 27,0:00:00,06/27/21,0:00:00,06/28/21
Day 179 Week 27,0:00:00,06/28/21,0:00:00,06/29/21
Day 180 Week 27,0:00:00,06/29/21,0:00:00,06/30/21
Day 181 Week 27,0:00:00,06/30/21,0:00:00,07/01/21
Day 182 Week 27,0:00:00,07/01/21,0:00:00,07/02/21
Day 183 Week 27,0:00:00,07/02/21,0:00:00,07/03/21
Day 184 Week 27,0:00:00,07/03/21,0:00:00,07/04/21
Day 185 Week 28,0:00:00,07/04/21,0:00:00,07/05/21
Day 186 Week 28,0:00:00,07/05/21,0:00:00,07/06/21
Day 187 Week 28,0:00:00,07/06/21,0:00:00,07/07/21
Day 188 Week 28,0:00:00,07/07/21,0:00:00,07/08/21
Day 189 Week 28,0:00:00,07/08/21,0:00:00,07/09/21
Day 190 Week 28,0:00:00,07/09/21,0:00:00,07/10/21
Day 191 Week 28,0:00:00,07/10/21,0:00:00,07/11/21
Day 192 Week 29,0:00:00,07/11/21,0:00:00,07/12/21
Day 193 Week 29,0:00:00,07/12/21,0:00:00,07/13/21
Day 194 Week 29,0:00:00,07/13/21,0:00:00,07/14/21
Day 195 Week 29,0:00:00,07/14/21,0:00:00,07/15/21
Day 196 Week 29,0:00:00,07/15/21,0:00:00,07/16/21
Day 197 Week 29,0:00:00,07/16/21,0:00:00,07/17/21
Day 198 Week 29,0:00:00,07/17/21,0:00:00,07/18/21
Day 199 Week 30,0:00:00,07/18/21,0:00:00,07/19/21
Day 200 Week 30,0:00:00,07/19/21,0:00:00,07/20/21
Day 201 Week 30,0:00:00,07/20/21,0:00:00,07/21/21
Day 202 Week 30,0:00:00,07/21/21,0:00:00,07/22/21
Day 203 Week 30,0:00:00,07/22/21,0:00:00,07/23/21
Day 204 Week 30,0:00:00,07/23/21,0:00:00,07/24/21
Day 205 Week 30,0:00:00,07/24/21,0:00:00,07/25/21
Day 206 Week 31,0:00:00,07/25/21,0:00:00,07/26/21
Day 207 Week 31,0:00:00,07/26/21,0:00:00,07/27/21
Day 208 Week 31,0:00:00,07/27/21,0:00:00,07/28/21
Day 209 Week 31,0:00:00,07/28/21,0:00:00,07/29/21
Day 210 Week 31,0:00:00,07/29/21,0:00:00,07/30/21
Day 211 Week 31,0:00:00,07/30/21,0:00:00,07/31/21
Day 212 Week 31,0:00:00,07/31/21,0:00:00,08/01/21
Day 213 Week 32,0:00:00,08/01/21,0:00:00,08/02/21
Day 214 Week 32,0:00:00,08/02/21,0:00:00,08/03/21
Day 215 Week 32,0:00:00,08/03/21,0:00:00,08/04/21
Day 216 Week 32,0:00:00,08/04/21,0:00:00,08/05/21
Day 217 Week 32,0:00:00,08/05/21,0:00:00,08/06/21
Day 218 Week 32,0:00:00,08/06/21,0:00:00,08/07/21
Day 219 Week 32,0:00:00,08/07/21,0:00:00,08/08/21
Day 220 Week 33,0:00:00,08/08/21,0:00:00,08/09/21
Day 221 Week 33,0:00:00,08/09/21,0:00:00,08/10/21
Day 222 Week 33,0:00:00,08/10/21,0:00:00,08/11/21
Day 223 Week 33,0:00:00,08/11/21,0:00:00,08/12/21
Day 224 Week 33,0:00:00,08/12/21,0:00:00,08/13/21
Day 225 Week 33,0:00:00,08/13/21,0:00:00,08/14/21
Day 226 Week 33,0:00:00,08/14/21,0:00:00,08/15/21
Day 227 Week 34,0:00:00,08/15/21,0:00:00,08/16/21
Day 228 Week 34,0:00:00,08/16/21,0:00:00,08/17/21
Day 229 Week 34,0:00:00,08/17/21,0:00:00,08/18/21
Day 230 Week 34,0:00:00,08/18/21,0:00:00,08/19/21
Day 231 Week 34,0:00:00,08/19/21,0:00:00,08/20/21
Day 232 Week 34,0:00:00,08/20/21,0:00:00,08/21/21
Day 233 Week 34,0:00:00,08/21/21,0:00:00,08/22/21
Day 234 Week 35,0:00:00,08/22/21,0:00:00,08/23/21
Day 235 Week 35,0:00:00,08/23/21,0:00:00,08/24/21
Day 236 Week 35,0:00:00,08/24/21,0:00:00,08/25/21
Day 237 Week 35,0:00:00,08/25/21,0:00:00,08/26/21
Day 238 Week 35,0:00:00,08/26/21,0:00:00,08/27/21
Day 239 Week 35,0:00:00,08/27/21,0:00:00,08/28/21
Day 240 Week 35,0:00:00,08/28/21,0:00:00,08/29/21
Day 241 Week 36,0:00:00,08/29/21,0:00:00,08/30/21
Day 242 Week 36,0:00:00,08/30/21,0:00:00,08/31/21
Day 243 Week 36,0:00:00,08/31/21,0:00:00,09/01/21
Day 244 Week 36,0:00:00,09/01/21,0:00:00,09/02/21
Day 245 Week 36,0:00:00,09/02/21,0:00:00,09/03/21
Day 246 Week 36,0:00:00,09/03/21,0:00:00,09/04/21
Day 247 Week 36,0:00:00,09/04/21,0:00:00,09/05/21
Day 248 Week 37,0:00:00,09/05/21,0:00:00,09/06/21
Day 249 Week 37,0:00:00,09/06/21,0:00:00,09/07/21
Day 250 Week 37,0:00:00,09/07/21,0:00:00,09/08/21
Day 251 Week 37,0:00:00,09/08/21,0:00:00,09/09/21
Day 252 Week 37,0:00:00,09/09/21,0:00:00,09/10/21
Day 253 Week 37,0:00:00,09/10/21,0:00:00,09/11/21
Day 254 Week 37,0:00:00,09/11/21,0:00:00,09/12/21
Day 255 Week 38,0:00:00,09/12/21,0:00:00,09/13/21
Day 256 Week 38,0:00:00,09/13/21,0:00:00,09/14/21
Day 257 Week 38,0:00:00,09/14/21,0:00:00,09/15/21
Day 258 Week 38,0:00:00,09/15/21,0:00:00,09/16/21
Day 259 Week 38,0:00:00,09/16/21,0:00:00,09/17/21
Day 260 Week 38,0:00:00,09/17/21,0:00:00,09/18/21
Day 261 Week 38,0:00:00,09/18/21,0:00:00,09/19/21
Day 262 Week 39,0:00:00,09/19/21,0:00:00,09/20/21
Day 263 Week 39,0:00:00,09/20/21,0:00:00,09/21/21
Day 264 Week 39,0:00:00,09/21/21,0:00:00,09/22/21
Day 265 Week 39,0:00:00,09/22/21,0:00:00,09/23/21
Day 266 Week 39,0:00:00,09/23/21,0:00:00,09/24/21
Day 267 Week 39,0:00:00,09/24/21,0:00:00,09/25/21
Day 268 Week 39,0:00:00,09/25/21,0:00:00,09/26/21
Day 269 Week 40,0:00:00,09/26/21,0:00:00,09/27/21
Day 270 Week 40,0:00:00,09/27/21,0:00:00,09/28/21
Day 271 Week 40,0:00:00,09/28/21,0:00:00,09/29/21
Day 272 Week 40,0:00:00,09/29/21,0:00:00,09/30/21
Day 273 Week 40,0:00:00,09/30/21,0:00:00,10/01/21
Day 274 Week 40,0:00:00,10/01/21,0:00:00,10/02/21
Day 275 Week 40,0:00:00,10/02/21,0:00:00,10/03/21
Day 276 Week 41,0:00:00,10/03/21,0:00:00,10/04/21
Day 277 Week 41,0:00:00,10/04/21,0:00:00,10/05/21
Day 278 Week 41,0:00:00,10/05/21,0:00:00,10/06/21
Day 279 Week 41,0:00:00,10/06/21,0:00:00,10/07/21
Day 280 Week 41,0:00:00,10/07/21,0:00:00,10/08/21
Day 281 Week 41,0:00:00,10/08/21,0:00:00,10/09/21
Day 282 Week 41,0:00:00,10/09/21,0:00:00,10/10/21
Day 283 Week 42,0:00:00,10/10/21,0:00:00,10/11/21
Day 284 Week 42,0:00:00,10/11/21,0:00:00,10/12/21
Day 285 Week 42,0:00:00,10/12/21,0:00:00,10/13/21
Day 286 Week 42,0:00:00,10/13/21,0:00:00,10/14/21
Day 287 Week 42,0:00:00,10/14/21,0:00:00,10/15/21
Day 288 Week 42,0:00:00,10/15/21,0:00:00,10/16/21
Day 289 Week 42,0:00:00,10/16/21,0:00:00,10/17/21
Day 290 Week 43,0:00:00,10/17/21,0:00:00,10/18/21
Day 291 Week 43,0:00:00,10/18/21,0:00:00,10/19/21
Day 292 Week 43,0:00:00,10/19/21,0:00:00,10/20/21
Day 293 Week 43,0:00:00,10/20/21,0:00:00,10/21/21
Day 294 Week 43,0:00:00,10/21/21,0:00:00,10/22/21
Day 295 Week 43,0:00:00,10/22/21,0:00:00,10/23/21
Day 296 Week 43,0:00:00,10/23/21,0:00:00,10/24/21
Day 297 Week 44,0:00:00,10/24/21,0:00:00,10/25/21
Day 298 Week 44,0:00:00,10/25/21,0:00:00,10/26/21
Day 299 Week 44,0:00:00,10/26/21,0:00:00,10/27/21
Day 300 Week 44,0:00:00,10/27/21,0:00:00,10/28/21
Day 301 Week 44,0:00:00,10/28/21,0:00:00,10/29/21
Day 302 Week 44,0:00:00,10/29/21,0:00:00,10/30/21
Day 303 Week 44,0:00:00,10/30/21,0:00:00,10/31/21
Day 304 Week 45,0:00:00,10/31/21,0:00:00,11/01/21
Day 305 Week 45,0:00:00,11/01/21,0:00:00,11/02/21
Day 306 Week 45,0:00:00,11/02/21,0:00:00,11/03/21
Day 307 Week 45,0:00:00,11/03/21,0:00:00,11/04/21
Day 308 Week 45,0:00:00,11/04/21,0:00:00,11/05/21
Day 309 Week 45,0:00:00,11/05/21,0:00:00,11/06/21
Day 310 Week 45,0:00:00,11/06/21,0:00:00,11/07/21
Day 311 Week 46,0:00:00,11/07/21,0:00:00,11/08/21
Day 312 Week 46,0:00:00,11/08/21,0:00:00,11/09/21
Day 313 Week 46,0:00:00,11/09/21,0:00:00,11/10/21
Day 314 Week 46,0:00:00,11/10/21,0:00:00,11/11/21
Day 315 Week 46,0:00:00,11/11/21,0:00:00,11/12/21
Day 316 Week 46,0:00:00,11/12/21,0:00:00,11/13/21
Day 317 Week 46,0:00:00,11/13/21,0:00:00,11/14/21
Day 318 Week 47,0:00:00,11/14/21,0:00:00,11/15/21
Day 319 Week 47,0:00:00,11/15/21,0:00:00,11/16/21
Day 320 Week 47,0:00:00,11/16/21,0:00:00,11/17/21
Day 321 Week 47,0:00:00,11/17/21,0:00:00,11/18/21
Day 322 Week 47,0:00:00,11/18/21,0:00:00,11/19/21
Day 323 Week 47,0:00:00,11/19/21,0:00:00,11/20/21
Day 324 Week 47,0:00:00,11/20/21,0:00:00,11/21/21
Day 325 Week 48,0:00:00,11/21/21,0:00:00,11/22/21
Day 326 Week 48,0:00:00,11/22/21,0:00:00,11/23/21
Day 327 Week 48,0:00:00,11/23/21,0:00:00,11/24/21
Day 328 Week 48,0:00:00,11/24/21,0:00:00,11/25/21
Day 329 Week 48,0:00:00,11/25/21,0:00:00,11/26/21
Day 330 Week 48,0:00:00,11/26/21,0:00:00,11/27/21
Day 331 Week 48,0:00:00,11/27/21,0:00:00,11/28/21
Day 332 Week 49,0:00:00,11/28/21,0:00:00,11/29/21
Day 333 Week 49,0:00:00,11/29/21,0:00:00,11/30/21
Day 334 Week 49,0:00:00,11/30/21,0:00:00,12/01/21
Day 335 Week 49,0:00:00,12/01/21,0:00:00,12/02/21
Day 336 Week 49,0:00:00,12/02/21,0:00:00,12/03/21
Day 337 Week 49,0:00:00,12/03/21,0:00:00,12/04/21
Day 338 Week 49,0:00:00,12/04/21,0:00:00,12/05/21
Day 339 Week 50,0:00:00,12/05/21,0:00:00,12/06/21
Day 340 Week 50,0:00:00,12/06/21,0:00:00,12/07/21
Day 341 Week 50,0:00:00,12/07/21,0:00:00,12/08/21
Day 342 Week 50,0:00:00,12/08/21,0:00:00,12/09/21
Day 343 Week 50,0:00:00,12/09/21,0:00:00,12/10/21
Day 344 Week 50,0:00:00,12/10/21,0:00:00,12/11/21
Day 345 Week 50,0:00:00,12/11/21,0:00:00,12/12/21
Day 346 Week 51,0:00:00,12/12/21,0:00:00,12/13/21
Day 347 Week 51,0:00:00,12/13/21,0:00:00,12/14/21
Day 348 Week 51,0:00:00,12/14/21,0:00:00,12/15/21
Day 349 Week 51,0:00:00,12/15/21,0:00:00,12/16/21
Day 350 Week 51,0:00:00,12/16/21,0:00:00,12/17/21
Day 351 Week 51,0:00:00,12/17/21,0:00:00,12/18/21
Day 352 Week 51,0:00:00,12/18/21,0:00:00,12/19/21
Day 353 Week 52,0:00:00,12/19/21,0:00:00,12/20/21
Day 354 Week 52,0:00:00,12/20/21,0:00:00,12/21/21
Day 355 Week 52,0:00:00,12/21/21,0:00:00,12/22/21
Day 356 Week 52,0:00:00,12/22/21,0:00:00,12/23/21
Day 357 Week 52,0:00:00,12/23/21,0:00:00,12/24/21
Day 358 Week 52,0:00:00,12/24/21,0:00:00,12/25/21
Day 359 Week 52,0:00:00,12/25/21,0:00:00,12/26/21
Day 360 Week 53,0:00:00,12/26/21,0:00:00,12/27/21
Day 361 Week 53,0:00:00,12/27/21,0:00:00,12/28/21
Day 362 Week 53,0:00:00,12/28/21,0:00:00,12/29/21
Day 363 Week 53,0:00:00,12/29/21,0:00:00,12/30/21
Day 364 Week 53,0:00:00,12/30/21,0:00:00,12/31/21
Day 365 Week 53,0:00:00,12/31/21,0:00:00,01/01/22
```

2. Choose if you want to import this into one of your current calendars, or create a new one.  Creating a new calendar wasn't intuitive; I found a 'how to' at [easytweaks](https://www.easytweaks.com/insert-outlook-2016-calendar/):

- Open Outlook and hit the  Calendar icon in the bottom-left navigation panel.

[image: panel]

- Go to `My calendars` and select the down arrow to expand

[image]

- Right click on one of the folded out calendars and select `New Calendar...`

[image]

- enter the name for your calendar and select the folder to be placed and make sure the folder contains are calendar items.

[image]

3. Import the csv file into out look by going to `File`, `Open & Export`, `Import\Export`

[image: Open Import]

4. Choose `Import form another program or file` then `next`
5. Choose `Comma Separated Values` then `next`
6. Choose the location of your file, and whether to duplicate then `next`
7. Select the destination folder then `next`
8. If you choose to make a new calendar and only see the new events

[image: single event days]

then turn on `overlay` in from within calendar view

[image: Overlay how to]

8. Use conditional highlighting (as demonstrated above) to highlight or darken events as desired that start today and end tomorrow.

[image: Future Conditioning]