# Grey out items in the past in Outlook calendar

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, calendar

Because Outlooks emphasis on today is so minimal, I would like to grey out items in the past.

I found a similar solution here: "[Highlighting the Current Day in Outlook 2013 Calendar](https://superuser.com/q/631874/263918)",
but I don't see the (advanced) conditions in Outlook to simply grey out all items with an end date before today.

How can I grey out items/days in the past?

Comment: Have you tried setting a darker skin? In the File menu, there's a section in office 2013 where you can make things darker. It also changes the colors of the calendar.

Answer (score 2):

Just like in the solution you've mentioned, use Contidional Formatting for your Calendar. But this time on the Filter's "Advanced" tab, select Field -> All Appointment fields -> **End**. Specify **on or before** Condition and **today** (without quotes) as a Value. Don't forget to add this criteria with "Add to List" button.

Comment: Unfortunately recurring meetings will get caught up in this rule, even those in the future. Adding a rule for `Recurrance Range End` means that past recurring appointments won't get caught in this rule until the entire range has ended.

Comment: You can exclude recurring meetings by adding the "Recurrence" "equals" "(none)" additional criteria.

Comment: That just means that recurring appointments will never ever be grayed out, even after the final occurrence has finished. The OP wants all past items to be greyed out.

Comment: This isn't an effective solution. It will grey out items that take place today, so not just in the past. Also the recurring items are problematic.

Comment: You can use the "today-1" value if needed. As for recurring items... I will take a look at them.

Comment: Please keep trying. Badly needed. +1. I don't see the actual full answer above. just hints how to do it.

Comment: Use "yesterday" without quotes to avoid formatting today's appointments

Comment: You can also use "now" without quotes to get updates throughout the day

Answer (score 0):

I found a different way around this. Not being satisfied with the conditional formatting solution (- owing to the failure in recurring appointments not being affected), I tried just changing the calendar colour away from the default. (View>Color). Picking something more garish such as the bright blue, or pink, makes the subtle emphasis on today contrast more starkly with the grey background, so it's more effective.

Now I just have to put up with a fluorescent calendar .

Also, moving my Reading Pane (View>Layout>Reading pane) to the Righthand side and increasing its size, so that the day columns are narrower, makes it easier to differentiate them. (This is more of an issue on a large monitor than a smaller one, i.e. laptop).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1143396)